# In a $\Delta ABC$, if $r_1=1$ and $r_2=2$ and $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$, find area of triangle.

Tags: triangles

> $r_1$ and $r_2$ are ex-radii about side a and b respectively. $\Delta$ is area of triangle. s is the semi-perimeter

Since $r_1=\frac{\Delta}{s-a}$
$$\Delta=s-a$$ and $$\Delta=2(s-b)$$

From this, it can be observed that 
$$b-a=\frac{\Delta}{2}$$ and $$c=\frac{3\Delta}{2}$$

How should I proceed ?

Comment: I just assumed those were standard notations. I added their meanings though @YNK . Also the formulae are dimensionally correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\Delta = (S-a)=2(S-b)$ Now replace $S=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ we get
$$ c=3(b-a) --(1)\,and\,a^2+b^2=c^2--(2)$$
Also using $r_1=\frac{\Delta}{S-a}=1$
$$\frac{1}{2}ab=\frac{b+c-a}{2}$$
$$ab=\frac{4}{3}c-----(3)$$
Squaring equation (1) 
$$9(a^2+b^2-2ab)=c^2$$  Using (3) we get
$$9c^2-24c=c^2$$
Hence $c=3$ using equation (3) $\Delta =2$

Comment: I think it should be $\frac12ab=\frac{b+c-a}{2}$

Comment: That is correct   thanks I have edited the same

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
r_a\,r_b&=\frac{S_{ABC}^2}{(\rho-a)(\rho-b)}
=\rho\,(\rho-c)
=\frac{S_{ABC}}{\tan\tfrac C2}
,\\
S_{ABC}&=r_a\,r_b\,\tan\tfrac C2
=2
.
\end{align}